# I have question about a semigroup for a Cauchy problem

Tags: semigroups, semigroup-of-operators, inverse-semigroups

Let $(A, D(A))$ be the generator of a strongly continuous
semigroup $(S(t))$ on $X$. Then the following Cauchy problem
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\dot{u}(t)=A u(t) \quad \text { on}\,\,\, (0,T) \\
u(0)=x
\end{array}\right.
$$
has a unique mild solution for all $x\in X$. This is a well-known result.

My confusion comes when they talk about the value of the semigroup $S(t)$ at $t=T$. I can't see why $S(T)$ has a meaning (because the Cauchy problem we solve is only on $(0,T)$).

If anyone can explain it to me please.

Comment: The said Cauchy problem is usually solved on $[0,\infty)$ (instead of $(0,T)$). That is, the unique mild solution $u(t):=S(t)x$ is defined for all $t\geq 0$ (in particular for $t=T$).